# how to write a mathematical equation in ionic 5?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to write mathematical equations in ionic with code not by inserting images, I've tried using mathjax but it doesn't appear, then I tried with html tags and it works for simple equations, but for more complex equations I feel it is less efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an Ionic app with complex equations using KaTex. Specifically with ng-katex https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-katex